# If $K$ is an algebraically closed field and $F \in K[X, Y]$ is irreducible, then $\dim K[X, Y]/(F) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\trianglelefteqslant}{\leqslant \hskip{-7.8pt} \raise{0.9pt}\vartriangleleft}$
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. I will now state some basic definitions as I don't know how standard they are.

- $K^n$ is equipped with the Zariski topology. Any closed or open subset of $K^n$ will be understood with respect to this topology;
- The dimension of a closed set $V \subseteq K^n$ is
  $$\dim V = \sup \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : (\exists V_0 \subsetneq V_1 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq V_n \subseteq V) \, V_k \text{'s are closed, irreducible} \};$$
- The (Krull) dimension of a ring $R$ is
  $$\dim R = \sup \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : (\exists I_0 \supsetneq I_1 \supsetneq \ldots \supsetneq I_n ) \, I_k \text{'s are prime ideals in } R \};$$
- The coordinate ring of $V \subseteq K^n$ is 
  $$K[V] = \{ F \upharpoonright V : F \in K[\overline{X}] \} \cong K[\overline{X}] / I(V).$$

The problem is:

> Suppose $F \in K[X, Y]$ is irreducible and $V = Z(F) \subseteq K^2$. Prove that $\dim V = 1$.

What I know:

- Hilbert's Nullstellensatz: $I(Z(I)) = \sqrt{I}$;
- If $V \subseteq K^n$ is an affine algebraic set, then Zariski-closed subsets $U \subseteq V$ correspond bijectively to radical ideals $I \trianglelefteqslant K[\overline{X}]$ containing $I(V)$ by $U \substack{\xleftarrow{Z(I)} \\ \xrightarrow[I(U)]{}} I$;
- These in turn correspond to radical ideals $I \trianglelefteqslant K[V]$;
- In the above, irreducible closed subsets correspond to prime ideals;
- $\dim V = \dim K[V]$;
- I was presented a theorem that if $R$ is a domain and a finitely generated $K$-algebra, then $\dim R = \operatorname{td}_K R_0$, but it was said that the proof is somewhat complicated (uses an external theory), so I don't want to use that theorem;
- I can see how [Krull's principal ideal theorem](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supDim.pdf) can be applied to immediately solve the problem, but I wasn't taught that theorem either, so if possible, I would rather avoid using it. However, if someone's really convinced there is no easier way, I will accept that as an answer.

Now my recognition of the problem: obviously there is some $\overline{a} = (a_1, a_2) \in V$ and $(X-a_1, Y-a_2) \supsetneq (F)$ is a chain of length $n=1$ of prime ideals in $K[\overline{X}]$ containing $I(V)$. Also if there were a chain $I_0 \supsetneq I_1 \supsetneq I_2$, we can assume that $I_0 = (X-a_1, Y-a_2)$ for some $\overline{a} \in V$ and $I_2 = (F)$. As $K[X, Y]$ is Noetherian, $I_1 = (G_1, \ldots, G_n)$ for some $G_1, \ldots, G_n \in K[X, Y]$, which can be assumed to be irreducible since $I_1$ is prime, and pairwise unassociated. But that doesn't seem to give any easy contradiction.

From the geometric side, suppose we have $V_0 \subsetneq V_1 \subsetneq V_2 \subseteq V$ closed, irreducible, so again we can assume $V_0 = \{ \overline{a} \}$ and $V_2 = V$ (and $V_1 = Z(I_1)$ if we want a connection). Any finite non-singleton is reducible, so $V_1$ is infinite (in fact, if $F$ depends on $Y$, the other case being trivial, then the projection $\pi_X[V_1]$ is co-finite). But I don't see any contradiction here either.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $\dim K[X_1, \ldots, X_n] = n$ a result you know?

Comment: @Bib-lost No, but I can see that the answer easily follows from it: $I_0 \supsetneq I_1 \supsetneq I_2 \supsetneq (0)$ would be a sequence of length $3$ in $K[X, Y]$, which is impossible. Does it take much effort to prove the fact you stated?

Comment: Indeed. Looking through my course notes on the topic, though, it looks like that fact also relies on Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem. I'll try to think of an elementary argument for the 2-dimensional case too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed an elementary solution for the two-dimensional case.

**Claim:** Let $K$ be a field, $F, G \in K[X, Y]$. If $F$ and $G$ are coprime (have no common factors), then $V(F) \cap V(G)$ is finite.

**Proof:** As $F$ and $G$ have no common factors in $K[X, Y]$, they also have no common factors in $K(X)[Y]$ (this result is known as Gauss' Lemma and is an elementary property of principal ideal domains; Wikipedia and Proofwiki have relatively short proofs of it). As $K(X)[Y]$ is a principal ideal domain as a polynomial ring over the field $K(X)$, this means that there exist some $A, B \in K[X, Y]$ and $D \in K[X] \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ with $AF + BG = D$. Let now $(a, b) \in V(F) \cap V(G)$. Then $D(a) = 0$. This can hold for only finitely many $a \in K$. Similarly (or by symmetry) there can be only finitely many $b \in K$ such that $(a, b) \in V(F) \cap V(G)$. $ \square $

We can now tackle your problem. Let $F \in K[X, Y]$ be irreducible. You have already noted that $\dim K[X, Y]/(F) \geq 1$. We can show equality if we show that all prime ideals of $K[X, Y]$ strictly containing $(F)$ are maximal. So take a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K[X, Y]$ strictly containing $(F)$; take $G \in \mathfrak{p} \setminus (F)$. Then $G$ is coprime to $F$, whereby $V(F, G)$ is a finite set containing $V(\mathfrak{p})$, such that also the latter is finite.

Now we apply the Nullstellensatz to find that $I(V(\mathfrak{p})) = \text{rad}(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}$ (last equality as prime ideals are radical). As $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, $V(\mathfrak{p})$ is irreducible, whereby $V(\mathfrak{p})$ is a singleton. But then $\mathfrak{p} = I(V(\mathfrak{p}))$ is a maximal ideal.

**Disclaimer:** If $K$ is not algebraically closed, then the Nullstellensatz and thus the last part of the proof no longer work (and in general, the correspondence between irreducible varieties and prime ideals breaks down). One can still show that $\dim K[X, Y]/(F) = 1$ if $K$ is any field and $F$ is an irreducible polynomial, but this requires more work. One way to approach this would be to embed $K$ into its algebraic closure $\tilde{K}$, then consider the embedding $K[X, Y] \to \tilde{K}[X, Y]$. The *Going Up* theorem (many proofs online) allows us to 'lift' a chain of prime ideals from $K[X, Y]$ to $\tilde{K}[X, Y]$, whereby the two rings have the same Krull dimension, but the argument I gave for algebraically closed fields essentially proved $\dim \tilde{K}[X, Y] = 2$, so we are done. Alternatively, using Krull's *Hauptidealsatz*, one can prove that $\dim K[X_1, \ldots, X_n] = n$ for any field $K$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Over the reals $p=(x^2+y^2)$ is prime and defines a singleton but is not maximal.

Comment: I know, that is why no simple modification of my argument would prove the theorem for non-algebraically closed fields. I was just hoping that one could answer OP's question with an elementary argument for all fields.

Comment: By OP’s definition of dimension of a variety, over the reals $\dim V(x^2+y^2)=0$. I think we need schemes instead of point sets.

Comment: Right, I was focussing on the title question; indeed the statement in blockquotes no longer holds over the reals.

Comment: @Adayah Can you please edit so the question and the title are asking the same thing? Which question do you want, the dimension of the ring or the variety? (Or both?)

Comment: @ZachTeitler It's the same thing, isn't it. $\dim V = \dim K[V] = \dim K[X, Y]/(F)$.

Comment: At least the second equality (and maybe even the first, I am not sure) depends on the Nullstellensatz, which only works for algebraically closed fields. Zach Teitler illustrated this: over $\mathbb{R}$, $\dim\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2) = 1$ whilst $\dim V(X^2 + Y^2) = 0$. Now in your question you explicitly specified that you only considered algebraically closed fields so this is not wrong, but in the future, it is a good idea not to interchange different definitions which are only equivalent in some specific cases.

Comment: @Bib-lost I see. We assumed in the beginning of the course that only algebraically closed fields would be considered so I don't actually know which isomorphisms and equivalences rely on that assumption. I edited the title to include the algebraic closedness of $K$.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I hope your question has been answered. :) I added a small sketch for how the proof could be generalized to arbitrary fields.

Comment: Okay, I just digested your solution and I find it brilliant. I believe the key point is that if $F, G \in K[X, Y] \setminus \{ 0 \}$ are coprime, then some combination of them is in $K[X] \setminus \{ 0 \}$; it looks very fundamental yet it was unknown to me. Many thanks! Let me just wait until 24 hours have passed before I gladly accept your answer. :-)

Comment: That is the key point and it is a tricky step. I think it might be due to William Fulton (Proposition 2 in Section 1.6 of http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf), but it might be that he too found it somewhere else.

Comment: It’s not due to Fulton. Elimination (as in eliminating one of the variables) was known in the 1800s. For instance in linear algebra there is Gaussian elimination. For polynomials there is an approach via *resultants*. More modern ideas include Gröbner bases. In any case, I agree with both of you that this key step is amazing and pretty cool!